# Up to what extent can you prevent modifying existing code when using design patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, factory, strategy-pattern

I am taking a design patterns class in school, and have read through some chapters of Head First Design Patterns. What I'd like to find out is up to what extent can design patterns prevent rewriting of existing code.

Let us take `Duck` classes and `FlyBehavior` classes for example. I have in `public static void main(String[] args)` the following code:

```
Duck mallard = new MallardDuck(new FlyWithWings());
```

Am I right in saying that it is inevitable that you'll have to modify your `main()` method when you want to add a new strategy? In that way, you *are* modifying existing code, right? I am specifically referring to the part where a concrete strategy class is mentioned: `new FlyWithWings().`

If you implemented the factory method pattern in your code, you could prevent having a concrete class (`FlyWithWings`) from being mentioned at all:

```
public FlyBehavior returnBehavior(FlyBehaviorFactory factory, String behaviorType) {
    return factory.getFlyBehavior(behaviorType);
}
```

And thus, have the following line of code:

```
Duck mallard = new MallardDuck(returnBehavior(flyFactory, "wings"));
```

This way, a certain portion of your program does not have to know about what FlyBehaviorFactory to use. Yet, your `main()` method will still have to specify certain parameters in the returnBehavior method in order to know what factory will create what strategy. Thus, am I right in saying that you'll still have to modify `main()` if I added a new FlyBehavior class, and wanted to add that as a parameter to `returnBehavior()`?

Can one improve this situation any further?

Comment: You should have a look at [_dependency injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and the various frameworks for it.

Answer (score 0):

In the current example, you are hard-coding the parameters passed to your factory and are thus deciding the behavior at `compile time`.

```
Duck mallard = new MallardDuck(returnBehavior(flyFactory, "wings"));
```

This can be changed to plugin a particular behavior at `runtime` instead of `compile time` :

```
Duck mallard = new MallardDuck(returnBehavior(flyFactory, args[0]));
```

With the above change, you will never have to change your `main` method. Your factory can be written in a way that it `throws` an `exception` when a behavior recieved at runtime is not available :

```
if(behaviorType.equals("wings") {
   //...create FlyWithWings
} else{
  //throw an appropriate exception indicating that the behavior does not exist
}
```

That being said, it is inevitable to change code if a new behavior is introduced. Although, this change will be in one single place and as far behind in your application as possible, i.e your `factory` which is the whole point of `factory` in the first place. Also, when you create a new `FlyBehavior`, you are doing so by extending from an existing class. This is inline with the `open-closed principle`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is dependency injection, you are injecting the FlyBehaviour into Duck. Sometimes when using dependency injection like this you can have a chain of injections. For example if you wanted a speed strategy to be injection into FlyBehaviour you might have something like this.

```
Duck mallard = new MallardDuck(new FlyWithWings(new FastSpeed()));
```

It wouldn't be nice to have main and any other class that uses Duck to have to know about all of these classes and have to change everytime any of these did. A better solution would be to use a dependency injection container which is responsible for creating each of these classes. Then in main you can just call something like this

```
Duck mallard = (Duck) Container.get('Duck');
```

The container is responsible for creating all the instances needed for the injection. So to answer your question you will need to change your code when wanting a new strategy but at least this way it is only in one place instead of throughout your code which could be many files.